# Why not projected coordinate descent?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, projection

There is the method of [projected gradient descent](https://www.google.com/search?q=projected%20gradient%20descent&oq=projected%20gradient%20descent&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l3j0i512j69i60j69i61j69i60.104j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Why there is no [projected coordinate descent](https://www.google.com/search?q=projected%20coordinate%20descent&oq=projected%20coordinate%20descent&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2.148j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

---

Suppose $f$ is a smooth and convex function we would like to minimize. Yet, we would like the minimizer to be in a convex set $\mathcal{X}$.

For projected gradient descent, it is simply

$$x^{(t+1)} = \mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{X}} \left( x^{(t)} -\alpha_t \nabla f \left( x^{(t)} \right) \right)$$

for the $(t+1)^{th}$ iteration.

Why is there no "projected coordinate descent"? I imagine it to be

$$x^{(t+1)} = \mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{X}} \left(\arg\min_y f \left( \dots,x_i^{(t+1)},y,x_{i+1}^{(t)}\dots \right)\right),$$

i.e., minimizing the $i^{th}$ coordinate while fixing other coordinates and then project onto $\mathcal{X}$.

I wonder why it is so difficult that nobody ever studied it before?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent

Comment: Projected coordinate descent. Not coordinate descent.

Comment: I believe you could get stuck at a non optimal point. Something like $X=\{(x,y) | |x|+|y| \le 1 \}$, $f(x,y) = y$, start at $({1 \over 2}, 0)$. Pick a 'bad' minimiser for the $x$ coordinate descent.

Comment: Thanks! But if choose y coordinate instead of x, it seems this can be solved. We don't have to follow cyclic order